# SQL Select instance of substring in column to get right salutation from address

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a large dataset where salutations are only in an address line, not in a salutation/prefix column, and I need to select them separately.

I've tried queries like `WHEN type address1 LIKE '%Ms' THEN 'Ms''` but this is obviously not working when address has multiple salutations.

Is there a to select the nth instance of an array of supplied values ('Mr', 'Mrs' etc..) based on a different column, Eg: Select 2nd instance of matching value in array when column is LIKE 'secondary%'?

Data

| name | lname | address1 | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah | Cho | Ms Sarah Cho | primary account |
| Mark | Reed | Mr Mark and Mrs Kim Reed | primary account |
| Kim | Reed | Mr Mark and Mrs Kim Reed | secondary account |

Desired output

| prefix | fname | lname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ms | Sarah | Cho |
| Mr | Mark | Reed |
| Mrs | Kim | Reed |

Comment: You don't. Simply put. Any assumptions you make about the name(s) will be wrong.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Thank you Larnu, very good caution. But if this particular data set has predictable pattern of limited Saultations, I thought this would be possible.

Comment: @Larnu Feels like a gold article, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @t TABLE (
  FName    VARCHAR(30),
  LName    VARCHAR(30),
  address1 VARCHAR(100),
  AccType  VARCHAR(20));

INSERT @t
VALUES
('Sarah', 'Cho',  'Ms Sarah Cho',                'primary account'),
('Mark',  'Reed', 'Mr Mark and Mrs Kim Reed',    'primary account'),
('Kim',   'Reed', 'Mr Mark and Mrs Kim Reed',    'secondary account'),
('Fred',  'Smith','Mr Fred and Mrs Betty Smith', 'Primary account'),
('Betty', 'Smith','Mr Fred and Mrs Betty Smith', 'secondary account');


-- Solution
SELECT
  Prefix = IIF(t.AccType = 'primary account',
           RTRIM(LEFT(t.address1,3)),
           SUBSTRING(sec.AcctName,1,pfx.Pos-1)),
  FName  = t.FName,
  LName  = t.LName
FROM   @t AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(t.address1,
                    CHARINDEX(' and ',t.address1)+5,100))) AS sec(AcctName)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(' ',sec.AcctName)))          AS pfx(Pos);
```

**Returns:**

```
Prefix  FName     LName
------- --------- ------------------------------
Ms      Sarah     Cho
Mr      Mark      Reed
Mrs     Kim       Reed
Mr      Fred      Smith
Mrs     Betty     Smith
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is get the leading salutation from the address, you may use:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(address1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', address1) - 1) AS prefix,
       name AS fname, lname
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: This returns `Mr Kim Reed`